# How do I get a specific EntityManager?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entity

I have an entity with ~70 variables. And I want to make some custom queries for searching for filtering, using different combinations of them, without having to create 10 000 find methods and then applying some logic to pick the correct one to use.

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

private CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;

public PageImpl<TClaimModel> findAllWithFilters(TClaimModelSearchCriteria filters){
    if (criteriaBuilder == null) criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<TClaimModel> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(TClaimModel.class);
    Root<TClaimModel> claimRoot = criteriaQuery.from(TClaimModel.class);
    Predicate predicate = getPredicate(filters, claimRoot);
    criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
    
    if(filters.getSortDirection().equals(Sort.Direction.ASC)) 
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(claimRoot.get(filters.getSort())));
    else
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(claimRoot.get(filters.getSort())));
    
    TypedQuery<TClaimModel> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    typedQuery.setFirstResult(filters.getPage() * filters.getPageSize());
    typedQuery.setMaxResults(filters.getPageSize());
    long claimsCount = getClaimsCount(predicate);
    
    return new PageImpl<>(typedQuery.getResultList(), filters.getPageable(), claimsCount);
}

private Predicate getPredicate(TClaimModelSearchCriteria filters, Root<TClaimModel> claimRoot) {
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    if (Objects.nonNull(filters.getClaimNum()))
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(claimRoot.get("claimNum"), "%" + filters.getClaimNum() + "%"));
    if (Objects.nonNull(filters.getClaimDate()))
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(claimRoot.get("claimDate"), filters.getClaimDate()));
    if (Objects.nonNull(filters.getStartSearchDate())) {
        if (Objects.nonNull(filters.getEndSearchDate()))
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.between(claimRoot.get("claimDate"), filters.getStartSearchDate(), filters.getEndSearchDate()));
        else
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(claimRoot.get("claimDate"), filters.getStartSearchDate()));
    } else if (Objects.nonNull(filters.getEndSearchDate()))
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(claimRoot.get("claimDate"), filters.getEndSearchDate()));
    // repeat for each possible filter;
    return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
}

private long getClaimsCount(Predicate predicate) {
    CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<TClaimModel> countRoot = countQuery.from(TClaimModel.class);
    countQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(countRoot)).where(predicate);
    return entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
}
```

This is my filtering code so far, but I get an error "Not an entity: class com.activiti.entities.alfresco.TClaimModel". After reading about this error, it turns out that I can't use @PersistenceContext to get the EntityManager.
So then, HOW do I get the EntityManager? I can autowire an EntityManagerFactory, but it doesn't have the createQuery method.

EDIT: The project is using 2 databases. Using @Autowire on the EntityManager also doesn't work, as I get:

Field entityManager in com.activiti.repository.alfresco.TClaimCriteriaRepository required a single bean, but 2 were found:
- org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0: defined by method 'createSharedEntityManager' in null
- org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1: defined by method 'createSharedEntityManager' in null

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I manually built the request...

```
@Autowired
protected DataSourceService dataSourceService;

public Map<String, Object> findAllWithFilters(TClaimModelSearchCriteria filters){

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        List<DataSource> dataSources = dataSourceService.getDataSourcesForTenant(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserObject().getTenantId());
        CommonJdbcTemplate commonJdbcTemplate = new CommonJdbcTemplate();
        if (dataSources.size() > 0) {
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = commonJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate(dataSources.get(0));
            String sql = buildRequestSql(filters);
            List<Map<String, Object>> data = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
            String counter = buildCountRequestSql(filters);
            Long count = (Long) jdbcTemplate.queryForList(counter).get(0).get("count");
            response.put("total", count);
            response.put("data", data);
            return response;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private String buildRequestSql(TClaimModelSearchCriteria filters) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("select * from t_claim");
    getWhere(sql, filters);
    sql.append(" order by " + filters.getSort());
    if (filters.getSortDirection() == Sort.Direction.DESC)
        sql.append(" desc");
    if (filters.getPage() != 0) {
        sql.append(" offset " + filters.getPage() * filters.getPageSize());
    }
    sql.append(" fetch first " + filters.getPageSize() + " row only");
    return sql.toString();
}

private String buildCountRequestSql(TClaimModelSearchCriteria filters) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("select count(*) from t_claim");
    getWhere(sql, filters);
    return sql.toString();
}

...
```

But I'd still like to know the proper way to do it :P